# set of discontinuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Define $D(f)$ to be the set of all points in domain $f$ where $f$ is discontinuous at these points. Suppose $f:[a,b]  \rightarrow [c,d]$ is Riemann integrable and $\phi: [\alpha,\beta] \rightarrow [a,b]$ is continuous, bijective and it satisfies $|\phi^{-1}(x)-\phi^{-1}(y)| \leq M|x-y|$ for some constant $M$.

Prove that $\phi(D(f \circ \phi))=D(f)$.

I let $x \in D(f)$. Then I got nowhere. Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote.